# Doesn't kibbutz also mean to build consensus?

Tags: meaning, yiddish

Merriam-Webster only defines [kibbutz](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kibbutz) as a settlement. I'm familiar with a usage that means to meet with a smaller group as part of a consensus building process, similar to Japanese [nemawashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemawashi)  Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: There is kibitzer, MW: broadly, one who offers opinions.

Comment: Where did you hear this usage? Is it in written sources? Could it be jargon specific to a company or institution? Was it from Jewish people? It sounds like a confusion with [kibitz](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kibitz) which can mean to exchange comments or offer advice. There's certainly no evidence that modern kibbutz meant anything else. The word kibbutz is modern Hebrew from the earlier Hebrew *qibbūṣ* meaning a gathering, community, rather than Yiddish.

Answer (score 1):

> —"Jesse was always really willing to—to kibbutz along with me."
> —"Do you know how to—do you know what 'kibbutzing' means?"
> —"Yes. Yeah. I like to kibbutz in the makeup trailer."
> (House: Swan Song)

This is one of only 3 hits for "kibbutz" as a verb in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), and it summarizes the sentiment I felt while reading the others: I think they really meant *kibitz*, defined by NOAD as "look on and offer unwelcome advice, especially at a card game" or "speak informally; chat". Since all three hits were from spoken sources, it's possible that they really did say *kibitz*.